# showing "Directory access is forbidden." in codeigniter,but it working in local system

Tags: mysql

```
       this is the Database.php file
```

it working in localhost but not working in the server ?
this is in codeigniter framework

```
     $active_group = 'default';
          $active_record = TRUE;
         $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
           $db['default']['username'] = 'gigaforc_bmo';
         $db['default']['password'] = 'bmo@optus';
          $db['default']['database'] = 'gigaforc_buildmyoffers';
          $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
         $db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'op_';
         $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
         $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
        $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
          $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
            $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
          $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
          $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
           $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: This sounds like perhaps an OS permissions issue.  Does the CodeIgniter process have the rights to access/modify that directory?

Comment: yes i gave 655 permission to index.php file

Comment: and 755 to Folder Directory!

Comment: Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: sorry I was not shouting, I was asking politely sir

Comment: Can u please help me any one